# Extract Normal Form from XML

Tags: xml, database, normalization

`<Historic>

   -----<ReturnData Year="2010">

             -----   -----<ReturnHistory>

               -----   -----<Return StoreDate="2010-07-31" Type="1">

                 -----   -----<EndDate>2010-01-31</EndDate>

                 -----   -----<ReturnDetail TimePeriod="1">

                   -----   -----   -----<Value>2.83</Value>

   -----   -----   </ReturnDetail>

   -----   -----</Return>

   -----        </ReturnData>

 -----<ReturnData Year="2010">

             -----   -----<ReturnHistory>

               -----   -----<Return StoreDate="2010-07-31" Type="1">

                 -----   -----<EndDate>2010-01-31</EndDate>

                 -----   -----<ReturnDetail TimePeriod="2">

                   -----   -----   -----<Value>1.83</Value>

   -----   -----   </ReturnDetail>

   -----   -----</Return>

   -----        </ReturnData>

   <Historic>`

I'm storing this in a table as follows:

Table Name = Historical

Columns

```
StockId : int  
StockCode: string  
Year:int  
StoreDate: datetime  
EndDate: datetime  
ReturnTypeId: int 
TimePeriodId: int
```

Is my table in the third normal form?

Would you recommend this structure or should I create corresponding tables for each parent node i.e. normalise it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from the structure, there's no clear way to answer this - whether a table is in 3NF or not is largely dependant on the meaning and the "semantics" of the data stored in that table.

I'm just guessing here: the `Year` column is most likely dependent on the `StoreDate` (or `EndDate`) column - right?

Also, more guessing: `StockCode` and `StockId` are dependant on one another - this also violates 3NF - try to put your stock information into a separate table:

**Stock Information**

```
StockId    INT
StockCode  STRING
```

and then keep only the `StockId` in your actual table and add a reference from your table to `StockInformation` on the `StockId` column.

If you remove those two issues, there's a good chance your table could now be in 3NF - but again, that depends on that data stored and what that really means - cannot accurately check for 3NF just based on the structure of the fields.